# Issue with Spring MVC Redirection

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i'm facing issue in Spring redirection. This is the first time i'm using modelandview in springs mvc 4.1. below is the code snippet

```
@RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    private ModelAndView deleteProduct(@PathVariable Integer id,final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
    {
        logger.info("Deleting product from database..."+id);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:home");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute( "message","Product was successfully deleted.");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

It enters inside the above method and throws an error saying The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (). (400 err code). If i remove redirection as below it works fine. But i need redirection!

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
```

Home mapping code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    private ModelAndView home(@ModelAttribute Product product) {
        return new ModelAndView("home");
    }
```

But below code is working properly for redirection (other functionality)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addproduct", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    private ModelAndView addingProduct(@ModelAttribute Product product,final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        logger.info("Product adding to database...");
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:home");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute( "message","Product was successfully added.");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Please help me in understanding the issue

Comment: see my answer, perhaps it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after using ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/");

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/home"); // from /delete/{id} Path
```